# Join based on condition without a linking/common column

Tags: sql, join

I need to join two tables based on some condition but there is no common/linking column.

[image]

I need to retrieve the fields of table B along with 'Actualvalue' from Table A. Condition is to take each RangeValue in Table B and Map with Table A to find where the value comes in between Range Start and Range End and get the corresponding ActualValue. Please provide your suggestions. Here RangeValue in Table B is unique

Comment: Please add the tag fr your dbms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try following query:-

```
SELECT B.*, A.Actualvalue
FROM B INNER JOIN A
ON B.RANGEVALUE BETWEEN A.RangeStart AND A.RangeEnd
```

Answer (score 0):

This query should do the work:

```
select tableb.*,actualValue from tableb join table1 on rageValue between rangestart and rangeend
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select *,
    (
    select ActualValue from A
    where B.RangeValue between RangeStart and RangeEnd
    ) as ActualValue
from B
```

There are some reasons that you might favor a scalar subquery instead of a join. One of the benefits is that it will error if the ranges get messed up and it finds more than one.